# Как декодировать json в go, возвращается в байтах?

Tags: golang

```
type ParseDate struct {
  event string  `json:"event"`
  data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

body := ctx.PostBody()
var datas ParseDate
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &datas)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(event)
```

> возвращается [123 34 102 114 111 109 95 105 100 34 58 50 51 49 48 55 57 54 48 55 125]

> body возвращает ответ сервера

Comment: Откуда взялась переменная event когда вы десериализуете в datas? В Println должно быть datas.event.

Answer (score 0):

Приведите к строке:

```
fmt.Println(string(event))
```